Find a $2$-dimmension recursive sequence.
Let $P(k,n)~(k,n\ge 0)$ be a $2$-dimmension recursive sequence
satisfying
\begin{cases}
 P(0,0)&=1,\\[5pt]P(0,n)&=0,&n\ne
 0,\\[5pt]P(k,0)&=\frac{1}{6}\left(1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}\right)(1+(-1)^k),&k\ne 0,\\[5pt]2P(k,n)&=P(k-1,n-1)+P(k-1,n+1),&k,n\ne 0.
\end{cases}
Find $P(k,n).$
I have tried to use the generating function as follows.
Assume $s(x,y):=\sum_{k\ge 0,n\ge0}P(k,n)x^ky^n.$ Then
\begin{align*} &\sum_{k\ge1,n\ge1}2P(k,n)x^ky^n\\[10pt] =&\sum_{{k\ge1,n\ge1}}P(k-1,n-1)x^ky^n+\sum_{{k\ge1,n\ge1}}P(k-1,n+1)x^ky^n\\[10pt] =&xy\sum_{{k\ge0,n\ge0}}P(k,n)x^ky^n+\frac{x}{y}\sum_{{k\ge0,n\ge2}}P(k,n)x^ky^n\\[10pt] =&xy\cdot{s(x,y)}+\frac{x}{y}\left[{s(x,y)}-1-\sum_{{k\ge1}}P(k,0)x^k-\sum_{{k\ge1}}P(k,1)x^ky\right]\\[10pt] =&xy\cdot{s(x,y)}+\frac{x}{y}\left[{s(x,y)}-1+\frac{x^2(x^2-2)}{(x^2-4)(x^2-1)}-\sum_{{k\ge1}}P(k,1)x^ky\right].\\[10pt] \end{align*}
I got stuck here, because $P(k,1)$ is not given.

Perhaps it helps that evaluation of the boundary values yields
$$n \neq  0: \quad P(0,n) = 0 $$
$$ \text{Even}(k) \land k\geq 1 : \quad  P(k,0)=\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}+1\right) $$
$$\text{Odd}(k) \land n\geq 1: \quad P(k,0)=0$$
In Mathematica the result looks rather simple
     TableForm[Ttb = Table[P[k, n], {n, 0, 6}, {k, n, n + 8, 2}]]

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{11}{32} & \frac{43}{128} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{5}{16} & \frac{37}{128} & \frac{9}{32} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{15}{64} & \frac{29}{128} & \frac{115}{512} \\
 \frac{1}{8} & \frac{5}{32} & \frac{21}{128} & \frac{43}{256} & \frac{11}{64} \\
 \frac{1}{16} & \frac{3}{32} & \frac{7}{64} & \frac{61}{512} & \frac{519}{4096} \\
 \frac{1}{32} & \frac{7}{128} & \frac{9}{128} & \frac{167}{2048} & \frac{741}{8192} \\
 \frac{1}{64} & \frac{1}{32} & \frac{45}{1024} & \frac{111}{2048} & \frac{1029}{16384} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
A full table yields
     TableForm[Ttb = Table[P[k, n], {n, 0, 6}, {k, 0, n + 8}]]



Can you give a full table including those $0,0,\cdots$, plz?
